# Map.containsKey is not working correctly

Tags: apex, map

I have the following code:

```
List<Lead> lList = [select id, email, company from Lead];
Set<String> aSearchSet = new Set<String>();
    for (Lead l : lList) {
      aSearchSet.add(l.company);
    }

Map<String,Account> companyToAccountMap = new Map<String,Account> ([select id, Name from Account where name IN :aSearchSet]);

 for (Lead l : lList) {
             if (companyToAccountMap.containsKey(l.company)){
                 system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, l.company + ' exist');
             } else {
                system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, l.company + ' does not exist');
             }    
         }
```

It just tells me the Company does not exist

The companyToAccountMap has the following data:

```
 (Account:{Name=My First Company,  Id=001Z00e000evIAG})

(Account:{Name=My Second Company, Id=001Z00e000eIAG})

(Account:{Name=My Third Company,  Id=001Z00w000ePEAG})

(Account:{Name=My First Company,  Id=001Z00s000evIAG})
```

When i use:

```
companyToAccountMap.containsKey(inquery.company)
```

I always get false

And im printing out the inquery.company

And it has 'My First Company', 'My Second Company', ...etc

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
Map<String,Account> companyToAccountMap = new Map<String,Account> ([select id, Name from Account where name IN :aSearchSet]);
```

The created map always has Id as the key, so you won't be able to lookup company name in there. If you want a mapped keyed from company name, you'll need to construct it yourself.

```
   Map<String, Account> m = new Map<String,Account>()
   for (Account a: [select .... ])
       m.put(a.name, a)
```

Comment: my bad, I led him wrong; I fixed the code in the original response to his original post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22687/calling-three-databases-in-one-soql-call/22691#22691